# Usage of NetworkCredential using c#

Tags: c#

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

what shall we put in the "username" field and in the "password" field

Comment: The username and the password registered at the SmtpServer for the user that want to send emails

Comment: The credentials of your account?

Comment: didnt get the idea yet, im working this system on my computer using visual studio. so what should i put?